# GridLayout: How can the CardView "exceed" the boundaries of the Grid?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, gridlayoutmanager

I have searched for days for the answer to this without any luck. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction on what I should do, I'm not asking someone to write the code for me. Please do not down vote, as to me, this is a question I find useful to be answered. If you know that this specific question is answered elsewhere, appreciate if you could share. I can provide more contextual information if necessary.

I am implementing a Recycler View with GridLayout manager. When I Click on the individual cards, I want the card to expand to show more information related to the card like in the picture example below:

1) Unclicked Layout - all cards have even sizes

[image]

2) Clicked card has bigger layout, all other cards remain the same. The rows below the expanded card **does not shift down**. The expanded card **overlaps the row below**.

[image]

I have read things like Wrap GridLayoutManager but I do not think that is the right solution. Other suggested solutions are creating a blank activity when a click is registered.

In my game, I intend to have about 50 characters at minimum. The recyclerview would also me to sort the positions of the cards. Thus, would prefer not to create the card positions manually. The 12 cards here are just an "excerpt" to illustrate what I intend to achieve.

Currently what I am doing is to have 2 layouts on my CardView. I just `setVisibility` to either GONE or VISIBLE when the card is pressed. However, what this does is to push the rows below down to make space for the enlarged layout. Additionally, all the other CardViews in the same row as the clicked card will be have an empty space below. This space is the difference between the basic card layout and the expanded card layout.This is very much different to the behavior in the pictures where the expanded layout simply overlaps.

The layout.xml for this page is a `ScrollView`. I have other components besides the `RecyclerView` on this page.

Does anyone know the method to implement something like this? Is doing a Grid Layout even the right step?

Comment: First what are you trying to do? A game? How many characters are you planing to have? 20-30 or 400-500? In the photo example you only have 12 heros... So why use a grid layout at all?? You can build the screen straight in the XML, it will give you a lot more flexibility, and it's not hard to manage the changes in the heroes if you only have a few of then

Comment: @ Leandro, thanks for the comment, i have edited my question. I would prefer to keep it using a recyclerview than doing building via xml.

Comment: You are right, my idea is a bad way to go. I will figure something out.

Comment: Just to put it out there, you could consider having an activity that is launched with a transparent background and it would contain the expanded version of the item layout. In order to do this, when you click on the item you would need to pass whatever details are needed and retrieve them in the activity. You could also pass the x/y position and size of the item and animate between them in the new activity.

Comment: Hi user, thanks for the approach. If this activity is started, what happens to the activity behind. I have a scrolling view as the parent layout on which my recycler view is placed. Would like it to continue being able to scroll even if the expanded version of a card is shown.